# sections of line bundles and etale schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$. We have the natural map on total spaces $f: Y \to Y_n$ given by $(x, t) \to (x, t^n)$ where $Y_n$ is the total space of $L^{\otimes n}$. Let $s$ be a section of $L^{\otimes n}$, then in some resourse it's stated that $f^{-1} (s)$ can be considered as a scheme over $X$ which is etale if $s$ is nonvanishing and $n$ is relatively prime with characteristic of the base field. (A source for this material is Danilov's *Cohomology of Algebraic Varieties*, Chapter 4,2.5.)

I'm struggling with it. We can take the preimage $Z$ of of $im(s) \subset Y_n$ which gives a scheme over $X$; can I understand this scheme $Z$ without passing to total spaces? I suspect that the map $Z \to X$ is branched at the points where $s$ vanishes but I don't see it basically because I don't understand how to construct $Z$ explicitly.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what is the natural map $f$? And what resource did you find this in?

Comment: @HankScorpio I realised that what I wrote is not correct. We have the natural map on total spaces (which takes (x, t) to (x, t^n)).
The source is Danilov's "cohomology of algebraic varieties"; Chapter 4, 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally on $X$, the scheme $Y\to X$ looks like $\Bbb A^1\times X\to X$, and the map $Y\to Y_n$ of $X$-schemes looks locally like $(t,x)\mapsto (t^n,x)$. So the preimage of a section $s:X\to Y_n$ is the fiber product $X\times_{Y_n} Y$ which locally looks like $V(t^n-s)\subset \Bbb A^1\times X$. It is now straightforward to see that this is unramified when $n$ is coprime to the characteristic and $s$ is nonvanishing.